# Crash in MobileCoreServices -[LSOpenOperation completeOperation]

Tags: ios, crash

I've received a crash report (iPod4,1, iOS 5.1.1) with this in a thread:

```
Hardware Model:      iPod4,1
Process:         AAA [969]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/33B2C5DC-78CE-4A99-9D5D-279DDF417DFD/AAA.app/AAA
Identifier:      AAA
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2012-07-05 18:16:33.606 +0200
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.1.1 (9B206)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xd055a967
Crashed Thread:  11

Thread 11 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                   0x346e5f78 objc_msgSend + 16
1   Foundation                        0x37f8a74c NSKVOPendingNotificationCreate + 216
2   Foundation                        0x37f8a652 NSKeyValuePushPendingNotificationPerThread + 62
3   Foundation                        0x37f7c744 NSKeyValueWillChange + 408
4   Foundation                        0x37f53848 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverNotification) willChangeValueForKey:] + 176
5   MobileCoreServices                0x33ffa00c -[LSOpenOperation completeOperation] + 32
6   MobileCoreServices                0x33ffa48a -[LSOpenOperation main] + 1050
7   Foundation                        0x37f61a7a -[NSThread main] + 66
8   Foundation                        0x37ff558a __NSThread__main__ + 1042
9   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x30f3172e _pthread_start + 314
10  libsystem_c.dylib                 0x30f315e8 thread_start + 0
```

Do you know what can be the reason of this crash?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: you are not providing the log header which specifies the kind of failure...

Answer (score 0):

My wild guess would be that either you are writing a code which shares some document or receive a document from another application (through "Open In" or openURL) and most likely you are passing some wrong address as parameter to some of API. However, it's hard to tell without knowing what you are doing and after which circumstances it crashed.